# how can i know the position in the php is header or not?

Tags: php

how can i know the position in the php is header or not ?

please see my code bellow:

```
<?php


// how can i check the position is header of not?
// header = no html outputed yet before test() run
// not_header = there is some html outputed before test() runed
function test(){
    $is_header=???;
    if($is_header){
        echo 'is_header';
    }else{
        echo 'not_header';
    }

}

test(); // 'is_header'

?>

hello world .... html outputed

<?php
test();// 'not_header'
?>
```

Comment: Could use [`headers_sent()`](http://uk3.php.net/headers_sent)

Comment: [headers_sent()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php)?

Comment: As others already mentioned: take a look at phps `header_sent()` function for such a test. But note that if you really have to test for this somewhere in the middle of your scripts, then most likely you have a serious problem with your architecture. Ask yourself _why_ you have to find out such thing in the middle of processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [headers_sent](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php). In general you should add headers with the [header](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function, so there's rarely a need to find out if headers have already been sent or not. Also worth reading in this context is the [runtime configuration for output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php).